# Import class from file of the same name

Tags: python

I often do this:

```
└─ mymodule
  ├─__init__.py
  ├─ MyClass1.py
  ...
  └─ MyClass2.py
```

And each file contains a single class, named accordingly MyClass1, MyClass2.

I know, I know, not pythonic of me, but I believe that convention should not limit my possibilities.

But, I encounter problems that I can not solve on my own - python import rules defy my logic.

Could you please help me, if not understand, but at least to have a way to do what I want. I want to compose my `__init__.py` so, that "mymodule" behaves as if all classes were in one file "mymodule.py".

I.e. from outside file, I want to be able to do:

`from mymodule import MyClass1`

And it would give me the class, and not the module, without having to do MyClass1.MyClass1.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: There is still time to make your file names (module names) more Pythonic: just lower-case their names, that's a start.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it like this:

```
from mymodule.MyClass1 import MyClass1
```

Comment: OP explicitly said they don't want to do that (for whatever reason)

Comment: I think they mean it as in not to do that inside the code every time they use the function @DeepSpace

Comment: I understand the question that he does not want to call MyClass1.MyClass1 in the code, but you interpretation can also be correct, so I am not sure.

Comment: "from outside file, I want to be able to do: `from mymodule import MyClass1`. And it would give me the class" is pretty clear to me, and doesn't support this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

In `__init__.py`:

```
from .MyClass1 import MyClass1
from .MyClass2 import MyClass2
```

Then you can use your import:

```
from mymodule import MyClass1
```